# maximizing mysql command line in windows 7

Tags: mysql, command-line, windows-7

appreciate your help!
i'm using XAMPP and the MySql Command line that included - when i try to maximize the command line it spreads only over half of my screen. Alt+Enter won't help. any idea how to maximize it? 
i'm using win 7.
thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the "Screen Buffer Size"'s Width via the Layout tab in the window's Properties dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can open properties of the window and set window size in characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) which also has tab support.

You could also try out [PuttyCyg](http://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/), but instead of a dos-prompt it will be a unix/cywgin bash prompt and requires a Cygwin to be installed.